# It is possible to set the concurrency mode for a Data Import Wizard job?

Tags: bulk-api, concurrency, data-import-wizard

I'm running in to some problems that I believe may be related to parallel processing of an 'Add new record' job by the Data Import Wizard.

Is it possible to somehow force the concurrency mode for the Bulk Data Load job created by the wizard to Serial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Import Wizard have the option to run bulk import in serial import as of now.

The other workaround for this is use Data loader in data loader you have option to load data serially using bulk APi.

Check "Enable serial mode for Bulk API" option.

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/configuring_the_data_loader.htm

Comment: I am trying to do bulk import in salesforce by passing data stored in csv format in small chunks to Salesforce. Currently when I am running the job flow Concurrency Mode is Parallel and batch size is 200. When I check the job status in the Salesforce corresponding to job id I get below error.
TooManyLockFailure : Too many lock failure 200. 

So as to resolve this I want to push the record serially. Can anyone suggest is it possible to set the concurrency mode to serial if Yes, then how? Thanks!

Comment: Open the Data Loader -> go to Settings -> Select the Use Bulk API option -> under that select Serial mode option.